# How do I make something respawn upon collision pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have been making a simple collecter game with enemies but I have no idea how to make the collectible spawn in a random position upon being collided with. Just like in many coin collecter games when the player collides with the coin, it spawns in a different spot and there is a scoring system I have tried too many times but it has failed. Please help! Here is my code:

```
#import some libraries
import sys
import random
import pygame
from pygame import mixer


pygame.init()
mixer.init()
pygame.font.init()
width = 1440
height = 810
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('test')
collectible_img = pygame.image.load('img/collectible.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(collectible_img)
white = (255, 255, 255)
intro = pygame.mixer.Sound('sfx/intro.ogg')
gameplay = pygame.mixer.Sound('sfx/gameplay.ogg')
coll_audio = pygame.mixer.Sound('sfx/cool.ogg')
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
score = 0
txt = pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/player.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 640
        self.speed = 10

    def keyboard(self, keys):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.speed
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.speed
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.speed
    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y


class Collectible(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/collectible.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 100

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/enemy.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.movementx = random.randrange(10, 50)
        self.movementy = random.randrange(10, 50)
        self.x = 900
        self.y = 500
    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y
def play_screen(end_it, cutscence):
    while (end_it == False):
        screen.fill(white)
        intro.play(0)
        bg = pygame.image.load('img/splashscreen.png')
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
        label = font.render("test", 1, (255, 0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                end_it = True
                intro.stop()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                gameplay.stop()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    gameplay.stop()
                    intro.stop()
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
    while (cutscence == False): 
        coll_audio.play(0)
        test2 = pygame.image.load('img/player.png')
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = font.render("Click to continue", 1, (255, 255, 255))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                cutscence = True
                coll_audio.stop()
                gameplay.play(0)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        screen.blit(text, (50, 50))
        screen.blit(test2, (500, 500))
        pygame.display.flip()

def play_again():
    player = Player()
    collectible = Collectible()
    enemy = Enemy()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player, collectible, enemy)
    collectibles = pygame.sprite.Group(collectible)
    enemies = pygame.sprite.Group(enemy)
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    global score
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    end_it = False
    game = False
    cutscence = False
    end_screen = False
    exit_screen = False
    while running:
        while (exit_screen == True):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
            exit_img = pygame.image.load('img/death.png')
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    exit_screen = False
                    gameplay.play()
                    play_again()
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    exit_screen = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        exit_screen = False
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
            screen.blit(exit_img, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                    sys.exit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player.keyboard(keys)
        all_sprites.update()
        global collided_collectibles
        collided_collectibles = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, collectibles, True)
        for collided_collectible in collided_collectibles:
            print('Collision.')
            score += 1
        collided_enemies = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemies, False)
        for collided_enemy in collided_enemies:
            exit_screen = True
            score *= 0
            gameplay.stop()
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        score_counter = txt.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(score_counter, (0, 0))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

play_screen(False, False)
play_again()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you hardcorded the spawn coordinates of your class `Collectible`. You could make a little function which generates a random number in range of width and height of your screen and pass it as argument when creating a new instance of the class.

Function for random spawn coordinates:

```
import random
def spawn_random():
    spawn_x = random.randint(0, 1440)
    spawn_y = random.randint(0,810)
    return spawn_x, spawn_y # returns a tuple, e.g (200, 400)
```

Your class needs some little changes:

```
class Collectible(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xy_spawn):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/collectible.png')
        self.x, self.y = xy_spawn
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))
```

When creating an instance for the first time `collectible = Collectible((200,100)` you can use your start coordinates where you like to spawn it to start with. After that, everytime the `collectible` should be spawned again (after collision or any other event) you call it like this:

```
collectible = Collectible(spawn_random())
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response! However, it did not work. I made the spawn_random function and changed the class and for when the play collided with the collectible I called it with collectible = Collectible(spawn_random()) I did not get any errors but the collectible did not respawn.

Comment: did you make sure, that you called the update to change the position of the rectangle? Because thats where the new instance is blitted.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I just learned myself the hard way in my own project. Every image needs to have a rectangle which pygame uses to blit to your surface anywhere. The rectangle with its image has no coordinates itself (if you check it after creating it, it is always at (0,0)), you need to update the position of your rect with the current x and y coordinates of the instance (like you do in your function update()). I hope I explained that well enough, still in the learning process myself. I'll update my answer how you could handle that in the initialisation.

Comment: In the collectible class, I have a function that changes the coordinates of the rectangle to self.x, and self.y

Comment: I know, thats why I told you, make sure you have called the update() function becore it gets drawn to the screen. Regardless, you can change them coordinates also in the initialisation of the instance

Comment: Thank you so much! I have got it working, I just forgot to change the self.rect attribution.